# how to change the type of a field in a model(a table) of the official module (hr) OpenERP

Tags: model, module, field, odoo, record

I wanna use the official hr module, But I wanna use my own fields. So I need to change the type of many fields.

eg. In the hr.employee, I wanna change the field:address_home_id from type "many2one" to "char". How can I do it ?

I know two ways:

First:settings->custom->model->edit.. It seems that I change it correctly, But it is not changed in the view.

Second: go to the source of the module;change the code:

```
'address_home_id': fields.many2one('res.partner.address', 'Home Address'),
```

to

```
'address_home_id': fields.char('Home Address',size=32),
```

But when I create a new record, failed!

Can somebody tell me how to get it right?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this from postgresql side. But you are doing it wrong. There will be many other relations or this field will be related to some other records, it will cause error. Try to add new fields for it.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I didn't add the --update arg. sorry for this stupid reason. haha.